# $a,b,c$ are all non-zero and $(-4\hat{i}+5\hat{j})a+(3\hat{i}-3\hat{j}+\hat{k})b+(\hat{i}+\hat{j}+3\hat{k})c=\lambda(a\hat{i}+b\hat{j}+c\hat{k})$

Tags: vectors

Find the value of $\lambda$ such that $a,b,c$ are all non-zero and
 $(-4\hat{i}+5\hat{j})a+(3\hat{i}-3\hat{j}+\hat{k})b+(\hat{i}+\hat{j}+3\hat{k})c=\lambda(a\hat{i}+b\hat{j}+c\hat{k})$

---

My Attempt:
I compared the coefficients of $\hat{i},\hat{j},\hat{k}$ on both sides of the given equation to get
$-4a+3b+c=\lambda a$
$5a-3b+c=\lambda b$
$b+3c=\lambda c$
But there are three equations and four variables.So i am not able to solve them.
I have a feeling that some linear dependent vectors concept will be applied here.But i am not able to apply.Please help me.Thanks.

---

EDIT 1:
As suggested by janmarqz,i found the characteristic equation $|A-\lambda I|=0$
$\begin{vmatrix}-4-\lambda&3&1\\5&-3-\lambda&1\\0&1&3-\lambda\end{vmatrix}=0$
$\lambda^3+4\lambda^2-24\lambda+4=0$
But the eigen values given are $0,-\sqrt{29}-2,\sqrt{29}-2$ which does not seem to be coming from my characteristic equation because $\lambda=0$ cannot be the root of my characteristic equation.
What i have done wrong, i dont understand.Please help me.Thanks.

Comment: the characteristic polynomial is  $-\lambda^3-4\lambda^2+25\lambda$... Observe http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=det+%7B%7B-4-L%2C3%2C1%7D%2C%7B5%2C-3-L%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C3-L%7D%7D

Comment: always there are errors that arise because of little distractions, I would recommend recalculate with a lot of patience, or experiment with wolfram alpha until you get plain satisfaction

Comment: Sir,i got it.Thanks for the help.

Comment: Good! that's cool!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In matrix form, the system of equations is
$$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-4&3&1\\5&-3&1\\0&1&3
\end{array}\right)
\left(\begin{array}{c}
a\\b\\c
\end{array}\right)=\lambda
\left(\begin{array}{c}
a\\b\\c
\end{array}\right),
$$
which means that the solutions are the **eigenvalues** and the **eigenvectors** of matrix
$
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
-4&3&1\\5&-3&1\\0&1&3
\end{array}\right)$.

Comment: with http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=jordan+form+%7B%7B-4%2C3%2C1%7D%2C%7B5%2C-3%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C3%7D%7D you can read both items

Comment: ,is not there a pure vector based method to solve it,rather than using matrices and eigen values?

Comment: in essence, the method of eigenvalues and eigenvectors are clever but elementary vector's and algebraic's manipulations to solve the kind of problems you are posing, if you haven't studied yet, well, it is almost about time

Comment: I know about eigen values,i applied in this question as suggested by you but the eigen values given by wolfram are not coming from the characteristic equation $|A-\lambda I|=0$,i am writing my characteristic equation above.